# How can I unpack this?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

here is the data. I want to unpack this tuple and print the message.

```py
shopping_list = [("fruits",'apple','peach'),('dairy','cheese','milk')]

#Use for loop to iterate over list and get each tuple for unpacking
   for item in shopping_list:
  
    #unpack the tuple into item and section variables 
    item1 = fruits
    item2 = dairy
  
   #print the message
    print("You can find the" "" "in the"  fruits  "section")
```

"Next, you want to use this list to print out where each  item is available.
The message could be as follows:
`"You can find the [item] in the [section] section""`
How can I write this??

I provided the data above. Please help[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What do you mean by unpack? Please edit the question to make it clear what you are asking for.

Comment: `for fruit, dairy in shopping_list` !? That would unpack things, not really makes sense for your list to have that data but regardless.

Comment: I have given the data guys.

Comment: what do you think went wrong in your approach ? what error message do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
shopping_list = [("fruits",'apple','peach'),('dairy','cheese','milk')]
for item in shopping_list:
    section = item[0]
    item1 = item[1]
    item2 = item[2]
    print(f'You can find the "{item1}" "{item2}" in the " {section} "section')
```